# How to move Site title and tagline next to the logo?

Tags: html, css

This is the link to my website: http://www.ishturd.com

As you can see here the logo is on top of the site title and tagline, I need it to appear side by side i.e. logo and the site title, the tagline will go below the title as it is now. Any help will be appreciated as I don't know any coding.

Here's the complete CSS of the site title in my style.css (sorry i didn't know what to post)

```
    .site-title {
    margin: 0;
    color: #171717;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 34px;
    font-size: 3.4rem;
    font-weight: bold;
   }

    .site-title a {
    color: #171717;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    }

    .site-title a:hover,
    .site-title a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
    }

    .no-site-tagline .site-title {
    margin-bottom: 22px;
    margin-bottom: 2.2rem;
    }

    @media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
    .site-branding {
    float: left;
    max-width: 50%;
    }

    .branding-right .site-branding {
    float: right;
    }
    }

    .site-description {
    display: block;
    margin: 11px 0 22px;
    margin: 1.1rem 0 2.2rem;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    letter-spacing: 0.1rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    } 

    .site-description a {
    text-decoration: none;
    }

    .site-description a:hover,
    .site-description a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you don't know any coding and are asking whole code? Sorry SO won't be able provide you a written code where you won't even try.

Answer (score 0):

I clean up the site-branding html, and the css:

HTML:

```
<div class="site-branding">
  <a href="http://www.ishturd.com/" class="custom-logo-link" rel="home" itemprop="url">
  <img width="151" height="105" src="http://www.ishturd.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/cropped-Ishturd-2.png" class="custom-logo" alt="cropped-Ishturd-2.png" itemprop="logo" sizes="(max-width: 151px) 100vw, 151px">
     <h1 class="site-title">
       ishturd 
       <br>
       <span class="site-description">The Honest Part of The Internet</span>
    </h1>
  </a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.site-branding {
  width: 600px;
}
.site-branding a { text-decoration: none;}
.site-branding a img { float: left;}
.site-branding a h1 { float: left; width: 350px; padding: 0px; margin:0px;}
.site-branding a span { font-size: 14px;}
```

you can further improve this code if you want, check the fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/Lvdt0ttd/